# find returning inverted results

Tags: linux, bash, find

In a few words a wrote this little script to clean up some directories where I had consolidated directories/files from multiple sources where I used the `cp` command with the `--backup=numbered` feature so that files with identical names would have a suffix like `.~1~` appended to avoid overwriting.  I then ran `fdupes` to remove duplicate files, in some cases `fdupes` removed the file which did not have the suffix appended from the cp command (the original file) so I wanted to scan the directories looking for files with the suffix appended by the `cp` command and if the file does not exist with the suffix removed I would move `mv` the file otherwise I would leave it to avoid deleting anything as `fdupes` did not think it was a duplicate.

The issues is the test condition `if [ -f ... ]` part of the code below returns inverted results than what it should and I cannot understand why. For example, when the file exists it would return false and when the file did not exist it would return true.  I fixed it by reversing the actions that I wanted to do based on the inverted return code and verified it was working as intended and it was so I ran it as such but would like to know if anyone knows why it would behave the way it did.  I am not a bash script expert by any means so its possible that I missed something simple.

```
#!/bin/bash
logfile=$$.log
exec > $logfile 2>&1

IFS='
'
#set -f

for FILE in $(find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*(\.~[0-9]+~)+$')
do
    FILE2=${FILE%%.~[0-9]*} # remove the suffix
    if [ -f "${FILE2}" ]
    then
      echo ERROR: "${FILE2}" already exists!
    else
      echo "${FILE}" renamed "${FILE2}"
      mv "${FILE}" "${FILE2}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I would go to Python or Perl for this.  Do an `os.walk()` on all the files, create a `dict` where the key is the suffixless name and the value is the most recent suffix.  Replace the value if you see a lower number, or unset it if you see the bare file name. Now, at the end, any entries in the dict containing a number contain the newest backup file for which thre is no main file; loop over those and move.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to see the problem by modifying your script to show both `FILE` and `FILE2` in the error message. There are a few minor problems with the script which could cause some confusion (but not the "inverted" logic):

- `find` output is not sorted.  If you had more than one backup file, a randomly chosen one would replace the original file;
- you could sort the output using an expression like `|sort -t~ -n -k2` on the end of the find-command.
- the regular expression allows multiple matches of the `~[0-9]~` pattern.  Conceivably you could have some odd file which ends with `~1~~2~`.
- the part where the suffix is removed assumes a single `~[0-9]~` is on the end of the filename.  An embedded `~0`, e.g., `foo~0bar~1~` would reduce `FILE` to `foo`. The workaround for that would be more cumbersome (since the suffix-stripping uses globbing), but could be done with a case statement which matched an explicit number of digits (likely three digits would be enough).

Comment: Yes, when I noticed what was happening I did have it so I can see both $FILE and $FILE2 and could not see anything unusual happening.  For file suffix I have .~1~ and .~1~.~2~ and as you mentioned I think the most I have see is three but that is not to say there are none longer...its many directories and thousands of files I am dealing with.  This is why I made the find command flexible enough in the regular expression.

Comment: The part that removes the suffix as I understand would be greedy (%%) and would remove from the first .~1~ to the end of the filename and from testing it seems to be doing just that. During initial testing I observed that the target files were being identified just fine, the suffix were being removed properly, but it was just that the test for file existence seemed to be inverted...very strange.  I tried to reproduce in a second test script and cannot seem to replicate the problem in that script.

Comment: There are a couple of possibilities for problems replicating (a) your script does modify the filesystem and (b) of course, "find" is not being sorted.